# find specific results in multiple joined and related tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search

I am not able to explain my question in abstract terms. It is a very simple question, but I need to go through this very palpable example. It's completely made up, and therefore should be comparable to simmilar applications.

We have a bunch of tables with information about users, all the tables are what I believe is normalized, some values are only references via IDs to other tables.

I am using mySQL ( and PHP with the mysqli extension  - in case that matters, which I doubt)

So here's for example what I have:

```
table user_data

=====================================================
|| User_ID || Name || age || gender || location_ID ||
=====================================================
|| U000001 || Paul || 30  || m      || L00001      ||
|| U000002 || John || 20  || m      || L00001      ||
|| U000003 || Mike || 25  || m      || L00002      ||
|| U000004 || Anna || 25  || f      || L00003      ||


table user_personal_info

============================================
|| User_ID || color || food  || profession||
============================================
|| U000001 || red   || pizza || architect ||
|| U000002 || blue  || pasta || policeman ||
|| U000003 || green || steak || plumber   ||
|| U000004 || pink  || salad || teacher   ||


table locations

========================================================
|| location_ID || country || state      || city       ||
========================================================
|| L00001      || USA     || New York   || New York   ||
|| L00002      || USA     || New York   || Buffalo    ||
|| L00003      || USA     || California || Sacramento ||
|| L00004      || Canada  || Ontario    || Toronto    ||
|| L00005      || Canada  || Quebec     || Montreal   ||



table user_activities

=========================================
|| activity_ID  || user_ID || priority ||
=========================================
|| A0003        || U000001 || 5        ||
|| A0005        || U000001 || 4        ||
|| A0004        || U000002 || 2        ||
|| A0006        || U000002 || 1        ||
|| A0001        || U000003 || 3        ||
|| A0002        || U000004 || 4        ||
|| A0001        || U000004 || 1        ||
|| A0003        || U000004 || 5        ||

table activities

=================================
|| activity_ID  || description ||
=================================
|| A0001        || surfing     ||
|| A0002        || exercising  ||
|| A0003        || baseball    ||
|| A0004        || theater     ||
|| A0005        || dancing     ||
|| A0006        || reading     ||
```

Alrighty, you get the concept, right?

to DISPLAY each entry, I make the following mySQL statement and then loop through the resultset in PHP and so on:

```
SELECT * FROM user_data
JOIN user_personal_info USING (User_ID)
```

in order to also display what their favorite activities are, I also have to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_activities 
WHERE user_ID = (current user_id)
```

of course I have to translate what the activity ID stands for and what the location ID stands for with additional queries...

*(By the way: Does anyone have a better suggestion for how to display all users and all fields associated with them, rather then doing two queries?)*

Now I want to build a thorough search function to find very specific users. 
I would know how to filter through my results using PHP, but that would require me to download the entire db first, and that probably takes very long to do, once a couple thousand users are in the DB.

I know how to find users who are male, female, or both, who like food or a color, who are from a *specific* location (location_ID=L00001 or so)... 
I know how to assign rules about ages (=, >, <...). I know about the LIKE %?% parameter.

My question is:

**How would I find all users from a certain country or a certain state?**
*How do I ask mySQL to only show those users,who's location_ID matches one from an array of location_IDs?*

**How do I find all users with one AND/OR more specific activities?**
*How do I ask mySQL to only show those users, who's array of activities matches at least all activities from an array (that would be the AND version)?*
*How do I ask mySQL to only show those users, who's array of activities contains at least one of the activities from an array (that would be the OR version)?*

And now the really important question is:

***How do I combine those statements with my normal statements from above?***
Meaning: *How would I find all users from NEW YORK STATE who are into SURFING and who are MALE and who like PIZZA?* 
or
*How would I find all users from USA who are into READING, and DANCING and who are OVER 30 and who like GREEN?*
or
*How would I find all users from SACRAMENTO, CA who are PLUMBERS and FEMALE?*

etc. etc. the examples are obviously endless!

I am sure someone will just be able to tell me "you should research this keyword". But because I am unable to express my question in a conceise manner, I wasn't successful finding much information...

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the answer. There were a couple of useful things I was pointed to, here is a summary of the things I didn't know but do now:

- utilizing JOIN more effectively
- the IN operator
- the GROUP BY operator combined with HAVING COUNT()
- and SUB SELECTS

Thanks for pointing those things out to me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think one of the keywords you're looking for is the `IN` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE country IN ('USA', 'Canada', 'Denmark')
```

would return all the rows where one of the values in the IN-clause is matched against the country field. So it's like writing this:

```
SELECT * FROM locations WHERE country = 'USA' OR country = 'Canada' OR country = 'Denmark'
```

As for the rest of your questions:

**Does anyone have a better suggestion for how to display all users and all fields associated with them, rather then doing two queries?**

Simply join them all together, like:

```
SELECT * FROM user_data
JOIN locations ON user_data.location_ID = locations.location_ID
JOIN user_personal_info ON user_data.User_ID = user_personal_info.User_ID
JOIN user_activities ON user_personal_info.User_ID = user_activities.User_ID
JOIN activities ON user_activities.activity_ID = activities.activity_ID
```

Of course, depending on your structure you'd use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN`, etc. It's also not a good practice to simply retrieve all data by `SELECT *`, but to really only select the fields you need.
Furthermore you could/should create one/more views representing the joined data you need and select from it/them.

**How would I find all users from a certain country or a certain state?**

```
SELECT user_data.* FROM user_data
JOIN locations ON user_data.location_ID = locations.location_ID
WHERE locations.country = 'USA' AND state = 'New York'
```

Depending on how you get the data from the user and how you prepare it for your statement in PHP. For instance, assuming your users searches for a country and you get it via a post method:

```
<?php
  $country = sanitize($_POST['country']);  // assuming a sanitation function for user input
  // whether by doing a sub-select
  $sql = "SELECT user_data.* FROM user_data WHERE user_data.location_ID = (SELECT locations.location_ID FROM locations WHERE locations.country LIKE '%{$country}%')";

  // or doing a join
  $sql = "SELECT user_data.* FROM user_data JOIN locations ON user_data.location_ID = locations.location_ID WHERE locations.country LIKE '%{$country}%'";
?>
```

The same principle goes for state, of course.

**How do I find all users with one AND/OR more specific activities?**

Here you would need to join against the activities table and use the IN operator as shown above.

**How do I combine those statements with my normal statements from above?**

Taking your example *How would I find all users from NEW YORK STATE who are into SURFING and who are MALE and who like PIZZA?*

```
SELECT user_data.* FROM user_data
 JOIN locations ON user_data.locations_ID = locations.location_ID
 JOIN user_activities = user_data.User_ID = user_activities.user_ID
 JOIN activities ON user_activities.activity_ID = user_activities.activity_ID
WHERE locations.sate = 'New York'
  AND activities.description IN ('surfing')
  AND user_data.gender = 'm'
  AND user_personal_info.food = 'pizza'
```

Hope this helps and gets you in the right direction.

**UPDATE**

Of course the IN-operator here could be substituted with `description = 'surfing'`, since it's only one value. And you're right if you add another value like `description IN ('surfing', 'reading')` it would mean `surfing OR reading`. So if you want to get all the users who are into `surfing AND reading` I guess I'd do it with a sub-select:

```
SELECT user_data.* FROM user_data
 WHERE user_data.User_ID IN (
   SELECT user_activities.user_ID FROM user_activities
     JOIN activities ON user_activities.activity_ID = activities.activity_ID
    WHERE activities.description IN ('surfing', 'reading')
   GROUP BY user_activities.activity_ID
     HAVING COUNT(user_activities.user_ID) = 2
 )
```

So the sub-select means: count each user-id that appears with a 'surfing' or 'reading', and if the count is equal to 2 (meaning they match for both) retrieve the user-id.
And the outer select simply selects the data from every user of the subset.

Now, I didn't test this so it may vary. And there are probably simpler ways. At least something you could do to simplify this query is to create a view as I mentioned before and select from it.

Comment: Awesome, this was very helpful, THANKS! But: what happens now if you add _"...who are into surfing AND into reading"_? you'd have to add another condition `AND activities.description IN ('reading')` right? But I think the result would then always be 0, because the JOIN is going create a new ROW for for each activity, so 2 activities are never on the same row...? On the same thought, say there is a person who likes 3 activities. Now suddenly I'll always have 3 rows returned when pulling the person up, eventhough its just ONE person. num_rows will not reflect how many people were found... ??!?

Comment: I updated my question accordingly. Ah and one thing I forgot is you could also work with `DISTINCT`. So if 3 rows are returned that are the same the distinct keyword reduces it to 1 unique row.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I updated my post as well pointing out what great new things you just taught me! :D